# Powershell connect to several INSTANCES of SQL Server

Tags: sql, windows, powershell

I need to create a script that do:

- Get services where name are like `MSSQL$*` (in order to get all SQL Server instances services)
- If the service are running, goes to check name
- If the name of the service is like `MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID`, throw a `System.Exception`
- If not, try to connect to every instances running on the server, if one of them are inaccessible, throw a `System.Exception`

My current script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
$running = Get-Service | where {($_.Status -eq "Running") -and $_.Name -like "MSSQL*"}
$services = (Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL*')
$running.Status | Foreach-object {
if ($running.status -contains 'Running'){

            if ($_.Name -ne 'MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID'){

                $instances = (get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances

                foreach ($instance in $instances){

                $server = "localhost"
                $database = "master"
                $sql = "select name from sys.databases"
                $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;Integrated Security=SSPI"
                $SqlConnection.Open()
                $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sql
                $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
                $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
                $SqlConnection.Close()
                $DataSet.Tables[0]
                $return = ($DataSet.Tables[0])
            
                if ($return -ne $null){return 1} else {[System.Exception]}
                }}
} else {[System.Exception]}
}}catch{[System.Exception]}
finally{$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"}
```

- Check status of services with `MSSQL*`
- If status of services is running, check name of service, if the name of service is equal to `MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID` throw a `System.Exception`, if not, list all instances and then, foreach instance in instances, try to connect
- If the connection is successful, return 1, if not, throw `System.Exception`

My questions are: with this script, doesn't matter how many instances have already installed in the server, only check the default... how can I make try the connection for every instance that is running?

I need to check the connection to each instance running on the server, if there is someone stopped, or inaccessible must throw a `System.Exception`.

And too, is not possible use dbatools, and invokesql...

Somebody knows how to make the connection to every instances running on the server, if one of them are inaccessible, throw a `System.Exception`?

------------------- UPDATED ------------------------

this string succesfully connect with an example of instance

```
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='localhost\NEWINSTANCE';Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
```

I just try to send the server trough variable, but give me error...

```
           if ($_.Name -ne 'MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID'){

                $SQLinstancesold = dir "SQLSERVER:\SQL\(local)"
               $SQLinstances = $SQLinstancesold | Format-table -HideTableHeaders

                foreach ($SQLinstance in $SQLInstances) {

                

                $server = 'localhost\'+$SQLinstance;
                $database = "master"
                $sql = "select name from sys.databases"
                $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
                $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server='localhost\NEWINSTANCE';Database=master;Integrated Security=SSPI"
                $SqlConnection.Open()
                $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
                $SqlCmd.CommandText = $sql
                $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
                $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
                $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
                $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
                $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
                $SqlConnection.Close()
                $DataSet.Tables[0]
                $return = ($DataSet.Tables[0])
            
                if ($return -ne $null){return 1} else {echo "else of return 1"}
                }}
```

I dont know how can I pass the variable to connectionstring in order to do the connection for each instance

--------------------------- UPDATED 2 -----------------------

I just modified the script:

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking 
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
try {
$running = Get-Service | where {($_.Status -eq "Running") -and $_.Name -like "MSSQL*"}
$services = (Get-Service -Name 'MSSQL*')
$running.Status | Foreach-object {
if ($running.status -contains 'Running'){


           if ($_.Name -ne 'MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID'){

               $SQLinstancesold = dir "SQLSERVER:\SQL\(local)"
               $SQLinstances = $SQLinstancesold | Format-table -HideTableHeaders
               $server = 'localhost\'+$SQLinstance;

                foreach ($SQLinstance in $SQLInstances) {
                $server = 'localhost\'+$SQLinstance;
                $return = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database master -Query "select name from sys.databases"
                
            
                if ($return -ne $null){return 1} else {echo "else of return 1"}
                }}


} else {echo "here"}

}

}
catch{echo "hello?"}
finally{$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"}
```

This way, list all instances, and for each instance declare variable server and try to invoke-sqlcmd

But, when I try to invoke $server on $return variable, give me an error, if I write for example the name of my instance NEWINSTANCE, return 1, that is correct

How can I put variable $server in order to get all instances on invokesqlcmd?

Comment: Try removing the ```catch{[System.Exception]}``` - that's specifically catching any exception your code throws and then silently swallows it. Also, I'm guessing here but for your ```else {[System.Exception]}``` I think you mean something like ```else{ throw new-object System.Exception }``` - your code is currently returning the ```System.Exception``` type to the output stream rather than throwing an exception.

Comment: Thank u mclayton

I need to get system.exception if there is any error, this script is for check the status of instances, if give me a system.exception, all the scripts automatized will not running

Im still working on it, and I got it a new clue (i think), editing the original posts with the new information